# can i turn off fast app resume on back button click

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

i have a windows 8 phone application, i would like to stop the app from fast resume when the user selects the back button after they have navigated away from the application. the nature of this application is that it should start afresh every time - just like when the user clicks on the applications tile.

i know there is the activationpolicy setting in the application manifest, however this is for the reverse purpose - enabling fast resume like behavior when the user selects the application's tile.

tia

Comment: Probably not, Microsoft doesn't want to expose any functionality that will hurt user experience.

Comment: surely at this stage the developer is better positioned to know which resume model is going to prove the better user experience. not everything is going to be resumable

Comment: ok then - is it possible to remove my application's entries from the back stack once the user selects the 'back' button. that way they can only select the application's tile to resume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps can only choose to participate in Fast Application Switching or Fast Application Resume. Developers can't pick and choose which pieces of behaviours work best for them. So you should choose the scheme that works best for your app using the ActivationPolicy in WmAppManifest.ml.

You could potentially catch the OnBackKeyPress event and invoke Application.Current.Terminate() if the backstack is about to be empty. I'm not sure if this violates any certfication guidelines or not, but Microsoft is very sensitive to back button usage and application lifecycle.

Comment: This and a combination of @inkog suggestion of actually clearing down the back stack helped me to achieve the flow i was looking for. In the applications navigate away handler i checked to see if the url was outside of my app's domain and then clear the back stack. finally calling app.Terminate() gives the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you’ve seriously thought long and hard about why your app should deviate from the norm and start afresh, then I would just clear the backstack on app resume.

Application_Activated

```
while (RootFrame.RemoveBackEntry() != null);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735579(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Howtoclearthebackstack